# ListView appers like sliding from bottom when button clicked

Tags: android

I am a novice in android. 
First, there is an empty activity then as user click on button a list view appears but in a bit of animation format i.e sliding from bottom to enhance user experience....... slightest help will be appreciated, thank you

Comment: can you post some part of you code? so that I can get some idea what you are trying to do..

Comment: Suppose when user click on top left corner a drop down list view appears in a sliding manner, like a smooth animation........ i have not started that activity till now

Answer (score 0):

I think you can Navigation Drawer fro this.

You can use Android studios built in template activity called NavigationDrawerActivity.

You can follow below links-

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html
https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Navigation drawer displays a ListView whenever Action Bar's icon is clicked.

You can use this for reference for making other kinds of activities also.

[image]

Comment: Note: Use Navigation Drawer only if the content of the ListView doesn't change. Else, Bad user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply animation on listview

up_from_bottom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="400" />
</set>
```

down_from_top.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
  <translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="400" />
 </set>
```

Applying Animations to ListView Rows

```
   private int lastPosition = -1;

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  //Load your view, populate it, etc...
  View view = ...;

  Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
  view.startAnimation(animation);
  lastPosition = position;

  return view;
  }
```

Comment: how can i get my individual string into view of getView()

Comment: suppose i want to display array of string in list view so what should i write inside View view=???

Comment: I want to get the animation when the list view appears ........ not when user scrolls the list

Comment: if you want to display array of string to display in a list view declare your string array and use that array using ArrayAdapter class and set this arrayadapter as an adapter using listView.setAdpater() method.....

Comment: you need to make custom listview adapter